# Group vectors with same first element into lists of vectors

Tags: clojure

I have

```
([AA moo foo boo][AA soo doo foo][BB woo roo too][BB koo ooo yoo])
```

I need to group it so I get lists of vectors with the same first element:

```
([AA moo foo boo][AA soo doo foo])([BB woo roo too][BB koo ooo yoo])
```

Is there a grouping function? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There actually is, and it's named `group-by`.

```
(vals (group-by first '([AA moo foo boo]
                        [AA soo doo foo]
                        [BB woo roo too]
                        [BB koo ooo yoo])))
;; => ([[AA moo foo boo] [AA soo doo foo]]
;;     [[BB woo roo too] [BB koo ooo yoo]])
```

`group-by` returns a map of the value that was used for grouping, as well as the group - so, since you're only interested in the groups, you need to use `vals` to access them.

---

Alternatively, if the elements are already in the right order (i.e. all starting with `AA` appear before those starting with `BB`, and so on), you could use `partition-by`:

```
(partition-by first '([AA moo foo boo]
                      [AA soo doo foo]
                      [BB woo roo too]
                      [BB koo ooo yoo]))
;; => (([AA moo foo boo] [AA soo doo foo])
;;     ([BB woo roo too] [BB koo ooo yoo]))
```